# How do I set up ubercart to be conditional based on a ups shipping quote?

Tags: drupal, ubercart, ups, drupal-rules

I am using Drupal 7 with ubercart shipping. My client want the cost of shipping to be ups ground quote unless it is >=$50. Then he wants to charge a flat $50.

I created a flat rate that cost $50 and a ups ground quote.

I don't see a condition that uses the shipping quote to determine shipping method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Got this figured out. Not pretty but it works. Just go to the ups option and add a condition with php evaluation. note that you must have two payment methods available for conditions to work. Paste this code.

```
$method = array (
  'id' => 'ups',
  'module' => 'uc_ups',
  'title' => 'UPS',
  'operations' => array (
    'configure' => array (
      'title' => 'configure',
      'href' => 'admin/store/settings/quotes/settings/ups',
    ),
  ),
  'quote' => array (
    'type' => 'small_package',
    'callback' => 'uc_ups_quote',
    'accessorials' => array (
      '03' => 'UPS Ground',
    ),
  ),
  'ship' => array (
    'type' => 'small_package',
    'callback' => 'uc_ups_fulfill_order',
    'file' => 'uc_ups.ship.inc',
    'pkg_types' => array (
      '02' => 'Customer Supplied Package',
      '01' => 'UPS Letter',
      '03' => 'Tube',
      '04' => 'PAK',
      21 => 'UPS Express Box',
      24 => 'UPS 25KG Box',
      25 => 'UPS 10KG Box',
      30 => 'Pallet',
      '2a' => 'Small Express Box',
      '2b' => 'Medium Express Box',
      '2c' => 'Large Express Box',
    ),
  ),
  'cancel' => 'uc_ups_void_shipment',
  'enabled' => 1,
  'weight' => '0',
);

$details->postal_code = $order->delivery_postal_code;
$details->zone = $order->delivery_zone;
$details->country = $order->delivery_country;

$quote = uc_ups_quote($order->products, $details , $method);
return ($quote['03']['rate'] < 50);
```

The method can be adjusted for other types of shipping this condition applies to only ups ground. You could modify this to automatically choose the least expensive method between ups/fedex or something like that too.

Anyway. Hope this helps someone else out there.